# How to convert a number to a percentage with SASS?

Tags: sass

I have a map that is 930px x 530px. I want to use a mixin to convert the lat/long coords to top/left percentage values inside the box.

This is what i have so far...

```
@mixin latLong ($lat, $long) {
    left: (($long + 180) * (930/360)) + %;
    top: (($lat + 90) * (530/180)) + %;
}
```

I use it like this...

```
&.m1 {@include latLong(-33.94628333, 151.2157139);}
```

This is spitting out a value, but it's in quotes, so it's invalid to css. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You want to use multiplication to apply a unit, rather than concatenation:

```
@mixin latLong ($lat, $long) {
  left: (($long + 180) * (930/360)) * 1%;
  top: (($lat + 90) * (530/180)) * 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using the native SASS helper method for percentages: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method.

```
@mixin latLong ($lat, $long) {
    left: percentage(($long + 180) * (930/360));
    top: percentage(($lat + 90) * (530/180));
}
```