# SCSS - Count font size with rem

Tags: css, sass

I want to setup a dynamic font-size counted from rem value for all my headers and I want to do this in for loop. My problem is that I don't know how to divide number to get this result:

- H1  : 40px (2 rem)
- H2  : 32px (1.51572rem)
- H3  : 26,3902px (1.31951rem)
- H4  : 20px (1 rem)

For loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  h#{$i} {
    margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
    line-height: (2.8rem / 1.33333333333);
    font: {
      size: 3.2rem - ($i * 0.8);
      family: $header-font;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont use an array of possible values instead of creating an algorithm returning the right number. You can create an array with `$myArray: (1,2,3,4)` and use it like this `nth($myArray, $i+1)` - see following post [Accessing an array key in SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079280/accessing-an-array-key-in-sass)

Comment: Yeah I solved my issue but still don't know how to divide to get dynamic numbers :/

Comment: Oh sorry XD I think the problem is the unit. To divide ignore the unit first and then append it. - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417081/doing-math-on-variable-argument-sass-mixins