# Add string to variable scss @mixin

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm working on my own mixin and I am having trouble printing out the string.

My code is

```
@mixin margin($val...) {
    margin: $val;
}
```

when I apply this to my style, I would want to just use numbers and not add the "px" after each number like so:

```
.somestyle {
    @include margin(10,4,50,3);
}
```

This would output to:

```
.somestyle {
    margin: 10 4 50 3;
}
```

Now when I add the "px" suffix to my code block, it looks like this:

```
@mixin margin($val...) {
    margin: $val + px;
}
```

I even tried:

```
@mixin margin($val...) {
    margin: #{$val}px;
}
```

All this does is add the "px" to the last value. So using the same example above, my output looks like:

```
.somestyle {
    margin: 10 4 50 3px;
}
```

How can I get "px" to be placed on each value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do math in a mixin with SASS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499633/how-to-do-math-in-a-mixin-with-sass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the "px" in a `@each` loop. Something like this:

```
@mixin margin($val...) {
    $margin: ();
    @each $i in $val {
        $margin: append($margin, $i + px);
    }
    margin: $margin;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7438814)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm a noob to sass and this really helps me out. You the man!!!