# Using an each loop with numbers as names and properties with SASS

Tags: sass

I have some CSS classes that are all similar, there are just two things that change: their `name` and `width`.

For example:

```
.col25 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%; // matches name
}
.col30 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%; // matches name
}
.col50 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%; // matches name
}
```

This is the closest I can think of achieving this:

```
@each $col in 25, 33, 50 {
  .col-#{$col} {
    float: left;
    width: $col + %;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jcdJt

But I cannot just append the `%`.

What would be the best way to write this with SASS, and allow me to easily add more if required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do math in a mixin with SASS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499633/how-to-do-math-in-a-mixin-with-sass)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had to use a `percentage` function:

```
@each $item in 25 33 50 {
  .col-#{$item} {
    float: left;
    width: percentage($item / 100);
    }
}
```

Compiles:

```
.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.col-33 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.col-50 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```